# Convert Date headers followed by AM & PM time cells to whole Timestamp column

Tags: pandas, date, header, timestamp

How to convert 'Time & Date' column to timestamp? As you can see there's a header cell for each date followed by AM & PM times. I would like to have a whole timestamp column.

```
Time & Date                 Country  ...  Consensus  Forecast
15                  4:00 PM      DE  ...        NaN       NaN
16    Tuesday April 02 2019     NaN  ...  Consensus  Forecast
17                  7:00 AM      EA  ...        NaN       NaN
18                  7:00 AM      ES  ...     -33.3K    -38.6K
19                  8:30 AM      GB  ...       49.8      49.1
20                  9:00 AM      CY  ...        NaN     8.90%
21                  9:40 AM      RO  ...      2.50%     2.50%
22                 10:00 AM      IE  ...        NaN     5.50%
23                  5:30 PM      DE  ...        NaN       NaN
24  Wednesday April 03 2019     NaN  ...  Consensus  Forecast
25                  7:15 AM      ES  ...         55      52.5
26                  7:45 AM      IT  ...       50.8      50.1
27                  7:50 AM      FR  ...       48.7      48.7
28                  7:55 AM      DE  ...       54.9      54.9
29                  8:00 AM      EA  ...       52.7      52.7
30                  8:30 AM      GB  ...       50.9      50.5
31                  9:00 AM      EA  ...      0.20%     0.40%
32                  9:00 AM      EA  ...      2.30%     1.80%
33                 11:25 AM      PL  ...      1.50%     1.50%
34   Thursday April 04 2019     NaN  ...  Consensus  Forecast
35                  4:30 AM      NL  ...        NaN     2.60%
36                  6:00 AM      DE  ...      0.30%     0.50%
37                  7:30 AM      DE  ...        NaN        54
38                 11:30 AM      EA  ...        NaN       NaN
39     Friday April 05 2019     NaN  ...  Consensus  Forecast
40                  6:00 AM      DE  ...      0.50%     0.70%
41                  6:45 AM      FR  ...     €-4.7B    €-4.7B
42                  7:30 AM      GB  ...     -2.40%    -2.20%
43                  7:30 AM      GB  ...      2.30%     1.50%
44                 11:30 AM      ES  ...        NaN      92.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Time & Date` column represents two different things, so it needs to be two different columns to start with. If there's a way to cut out that step I would love to see it, but I'm guessing you need to expand it into two columns before combining again before using `pandas.to_datetime()` with the `format` argument to get it into datetime.

First, get the dates into a different column, then [forward-fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) the missing values.

```
df['date'] = df['Time & Date'].apply(
    lambda x: np.nan if (('AM' in str(x))|('PM' in str(x))) else x
).ffill()
```

Then you can rename `Time & Date` to `time`, slice out the date columns in that row from the dataframe, and concatenate `date` and `time` together.

```
df.rename(columns={'Time & Date': 'time'}, inplace=True)

df = df.loc[df.time.str.contains('AM|PM', regex=True)]

df['datetime'] = df.date + ' ' + df.time
```

From there all you have to do is find the right [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for `pd.to_datetime()` and you're set!

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! However I'm getting an error with this code: ```mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2467, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "C:/Users/irmsc/pp/KerasFxModel/testLoadCsv.py", line 9, in <lambda>
    df['date'] = df['Time & Date'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if (('AM' in x)|('PM' in x)) else x).ffill()
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable```

Comment: Ok, it can be fixed by wrapping x with 'str' over here: ```(('AM' in str(x))|('PM' in str(x)))```

Comment: ```df = df.loc[~df.time.contains('AM|PM', regex=True)]``` - in your code here we are excluding, right? But we actually need to keep those with AM PM in this case. Also we need to put .str. in between: ```df = df[df['time'].str.contains('AM|PM', regex=True)]```

Comment: I wrote a complete step-by-step guide on my blog: https://texxl.com/python/pandas/convert-to-timestamp-datetime-pandas-time-column-with-dates-sliced-in-between-as-headers/  - just in case someone might find it useful. Cheers ;)

Comment: Yeah you caught both those errors right! Next time if you include sample data that's in pandas dataframe format or something that can be read with `pandas.read_clipboard()` (without elipses) the code will be easier to test.  :) Same goes for the `str(x)` issue — hard to infer datatype w/o data.

Comment: Great blog post btw! The only tiniest thing is that in pandas the convention is to keep column names in snake case.

Comment: That's right! I've uploaded the whole dataset to Github and shared link in my blog post so that anyone can read csv directly to Pandas dataftrame.